# Plugin not being interpreted

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I had to copy relevant files from an existing joomla application to a fresh joomla installation. After doing that, some plugins and modules that were working properly on the old installation aren't on the new installation. e.g

I have {chronoforms}Contact_Us{/chronoforms} that is meant to display a contact form, instead if justs echos {chronoforms}Contact_Us{/chronoforms}.

I also have {module _Story_Player} that is meant to display a allvideoshare video but instead just echos {module _Story_Player}

When i access the backend to view these plugins, i get a 500 - An error has occurred with xml missing note, eg, for chronoforms, i get The file chronoforms.xml could not be found although I have all the necessary files copied to the right location.

I have looked through jooomla forums and other resource sites but havent found any pointers so far.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do would be to re-install the software, as it appears you've missed the relevant configuration files for those plugins (you've probably also missed other files media, language etc).

[Chronoforms on JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508).

[All Video Share on JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-players/video-players-a-gallery/19866)

Most good extensions have no problem being installed over an existing or partial installation so you shouldn't encounter any problems.

As @Riccardo Zom, mentions re-installing will also make sure the extensions are properly registered with Joomla! for menus, ACL e.t.c.

Comment: You absolutely need to reinstall as the extensions need to be registered in the database too (for creating menus and more)

Answer (score 0):

What about "Extension Manager" > "Discover" - isn't that supposed to be used in such cases?

Comment: That would require the user to have successfully copied all files to the correct locations… which @kayfun has indicated he's missed some `XML` files at least and possibly others.

Comment: Ok, II see. I had assumed this msg was came up as a result of these plugins not being properly installed.